# Issues with Kendo MVVM file upload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm, kendo-upload

I was trying to get a Kendo MVVM file upload working along with ASP.NET. This is how my HTML looks for the upload declaration:

```
<input name="attachments" 
id="fileUpload"
type="file"
data-role="upload"
data-async="{ saveUrl: 'FileUpload.aspx', autoUpload: true }"
data-bind="events: { success: onSuccess,error: onError }">
```

and the FileUpload page load:

```
Response.Expires = -1;

//Code to upload -- This returns me the file url that i need to send back as a response
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write(fileUrl);
Response.End();
```

The page load written above does function as expected and return me the desired result but the kendo control here behaves in a funny manner. It tells me that the upload is unsuccessful as in the error icon shows up on the UI. Moreover it is the error handler provided by Kendo that is executed though the written response is returned properly when I try accessing it as:

```
e.XMLHttpRequest.responseText
```

Well I guess I might have missed out something/done some small mistake here or there but unfortunately I am not able to figure the same out. Anyone who could possibly suggest/correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the response for the file upload control should be empty or a JSON string otherwise it is treated as an error. I changed the Response text to thus:

```
Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(fileUrl));
```

to resolve.

Hope this helps someone else!